# how to send information form one page to another page using anchor tag and fetch data from database in php

Tags: php

page1

```
<?php 
                            mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
mysql_select_db("mydatabase");
$sql="SELECT * FROM user";
$result=mysql_query($sql);
                            while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result))                          {

echo '<a  href="user_profile.php?variableName="'.&row['userid'].' style="text-decoration:none">'.$row['username'].'</a></form>';
}
?>
```

user_profile page

```
<?php
mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
mysql_select_db("mydatabase");
$sql="SELECT * FROM user where userid=".$_GET['variableName'];
$result=mysql_query($sql);
                            while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result))                          {
echo 'username:'.$row['name'];

}
?>
```

Is it right way or not if its right, why its not working, i facing problem to send information to another page. if it's not right way than please suggest me..I need your help.

***I am not talking about the syntax error*** plz see my code and try to know what actual i want

Answer (score 1):

Looks like maybe the href attribute is not terminated with double-quote...

Answer (score 1):

" - is in bad place

```
<a  href="user_profile.php?variableName='.&row['userid'].'"...
```

Comment: hey that's great to find it....but it's not actual problem...echo '<a  href="user_profile.php?variableName="'.$row['userid'].' style="text-decoration:none">'.$row['username'].'</a></form>';.........**now tell me what the problem....** why am i not sending different - different user information to the next page

Comment: please inspect the link and check if the arguments are added in the url to make sure that the information is passed through the url